# JavaScript sometimes behave differently

Tags: javascript

This code is an answer for a question. So I would like to know why JS behave differently in some situations
The below code is functioned to remove the last one digit when clicking the delete button.
for example if i type 777887328758 or some long number with repeated digits and **click on delete button fast and repeatedly** , it **remove first digit or intermediate digit or sometimes last digit**. Why this happens?

```js
function del(){
  var num=document.getElementById('num').value;
  num=num.replace(num[num.length-1],'');
  document.getElementById('num').value=num;
}
function isValid(a){
  if(!(/^[0-9]+$/.test(a.value))){
    a.focus();
    console.clear();
    console.log("Please enter number");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="tel" onblur="isValid(this);" id="num" /><button onclick="del();">Del</button>
```

Comment: ya i also find this issue to previous answer to question you gave

Comment: it should not happen anyway but it is happening. what is the reason?

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with how fast you click the button.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because it's got a bug. See this line in `del()`:

```
num=num.replace(num[num.length-1],'');
```

What does it do? It takes the last character of num, and replaces, that's the bug, the *first* occurrence of that character.

Fixed version:

```
num = num.substr(0, num.length - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

use this to remove numbers

```js
function del() {
    var num = document.getElementById('num').value;
    num = num.slice(0, num.length-1);
    document.getElementById('num').value = num;
}
```